# How to make <ul> list "retract" when clicked off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<ul>` drop down list and all works fine but I'm wondering if it's possible to make the list "retract", so essentially disappear back to it's original state when you click off away from it?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpf7E/237/)

Here is the code that I acquired to make the drop down work. I'm no good with JS so I don't know what I would need to do or if it's possible to get what I'm after.

```
$(function(){
    $('#select').click(function(){
        $('#sel-option').show();        
    });
    $('#sel-option a').click(function(e){
         $('#select').text($(this).text());
         $('#sel-option').hide(); 
        $(this).addClass('current');
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})
```

Comment: Have you tried the `blur` event?

Comment: @Johan I have no idea what that means :S

Comment: Just as you're using `click`, there is another event called `blur`, which is triggered when you move the focus away from the element e.g. click somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you just have to handle body click event and prevent select click from bubbling (in other case you will not be able to open it)

```
$(function(){
    $('#select').click(function(event){
        $('#sel-option').show();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('#sel-option a').click(function(e){
         $('#select').text($(this).text());
         $('#sel-option').hide(); 
        $(this).addClass('current');
        e.preventDefault();
    })
    $('body').on('click', function(){
        $('#sel-option').hide(); 
    });
})
```

**UPDATED:** and working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tpf7E/239/

Comment: @ElendilTheTall it is working, but body size is too small - try to click next to "Language" :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(function(){

    $(document).click(function (e)
  {
    var container = $(".language");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        $('#sel-option').hide();        
             show = 0;
    }
});

    var show=0;

    $('#select').click(function(){
        if(show==0)
        {    
         $('#sel-option').show();        
         show = 1;
        }
        else
        {
             $('#sel-option').hide();        
             show = 0;
        }    
    });
    $('#sel-option a').click(function(e){
         $('#select').text($(this).text());
         $('#sel-option').hide(); 
        $(this).addClass('current');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

see [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpf7E/240/)